# How to select elements that has event attached by .on()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some HTML elements, that are added dynamically. I bound to them `click` event.

```
$(document).on('click','img',function(){
    // some stuff
})
```

How I can select all these element that has `click` event?
A want to make some CSS changes on that elements.
I'm able to select element with directly attached `click` or element with `onClick` attribute, but I'm stuck with event added by `.on()`. Basically I have to stylize icons with all kind `click` event, to look like buttons.

It's legacy code, and to stylize all icons I will have to change many lines, above 200 user modules.

As another thought, is it possible to override `.on()` and in that method check if event `click` is going to be attach to an `img` element, and if so, add CSS class to stylize it then call the original `.on()`?

Comment: If you already have the selector for the event handler binding, why can't you just `$('img')`?

Comment: It's legacy code, and to stylize all icons I will have to change many lines.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need jQuery to stylize them.  Since `img` is your selector, you can simply use CSS:

```
img
{
    /* set styles here */
}
```

---

That said, if you wanted to use jQuery you could do something like this:

```
$("img")
    .css
    ({
        // set your styles here.
    })
    .on("click", function() 
    {
        // perform some action on click.
    });
```

Comment: I have to stylize specified images, only those with "click" event.

Answer (score 0):

In the some stuff scope, juste add a class to binded elements.

Eg.

```
$(document).on('click','img',function(){
    // some stuff
    $( this ).addClass( 'bound' );
})
```

Now, you can use the $( '.bound' ) selector to do what you want (or .bound in you CSS ;) )

Regards.

Comment: This would only work on elements that have actually had the event fired on them, which isn't necessarily going to be the case.